# height of page on scrolling

Tags: javascript, gwt, scrollbar

How do I get the height of the page on scroll?

Is it possible to determine how much the user has scrolled the page and determine the position of length that it covered.

I have tried:

```
var scroll=$wnd.scrollTop
```

in `JavaScript` but it is giving result undefined?

Am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it using [GWT JSNI](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html).

```
public static native int getScrollTop()
/*-{
    return $wnd.pageYOffset;
}-*/;
```

For more info have a look at [window size and scrollbar position](http://www.softcomplex.com/docs/get_window_size_and_scrollbar_position.html)

Comment: I have tried  var scroll=body.scrollTop which is each to your ans

Comment: Yes there are other ways also at above mentioned link that I have shared. It is just one way.

Answer (score 0):

I used the next code to get the current scroll position of the webpage:

```
var y = $(document).scrollTop();
```

It worked for me.
(I hope that's what you were looking for)

Comment: var position= popup.offsetTop;
                   var width=popup.offsetWidth;
                   var positionpop=popup.offsetHeight;
                   var scroll=$doc.scrollTop();
                   alert("scroll"+scroll);

Comment: Check whether the variable $doc is NaN or not, because scrollTop() should work. I don't have any other idea.

Comment: thanks..but I have rechecked it ,but its not working.